# Jersey Root Resource member variable initialization

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-1.0

I've inherited a little web application that contains root resources that are similar to:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("somepath")
public class ResourceClass
{
   DataSource source = new SpecificDataSource();
   @GET
   public String getInfo() {
      return source.queryThatReturnsNumber().toString();
   }
}
```

And there are a few different classes similar to this.  Is there a method to set the source member variable to something other than SpecificDataSource?  I'm fairly new to this, but in a traditional POJO I would have a constructor that takes a class implementing the DataSource interface and sets source to that object.  For Jersey, I don't believe that I have direct control over the construction of these objects.

Simply put, is there a way to provide an initialization mechanism for Jersey Root Resource classes?

Comment: Look into jersey-spring integration and use dependency injection.

Comment: Are you fairly sure that the constructor is never called during the creation of ResoureClass Objects? I am almost certain that regardless of what kind of resource you have, at lower level the object creation in JVM will not change (assuming that you are using a default constructor and not some special constructor). Easiest way to test is created a default constructor public ResourceClass() {System.out.println("HI FROM CONSTRUCTOR");}, call /somepath using some rest client (or browser) and see in the logs if you see this log statement. I would assume it will log the SOP on every call.

Comment: This should probably tell you if the constructor is getting called or not. If not (i will have to try), then you will have to inject the object some other way, but from my guessings I am certain that it should call the default constructor on object creation. This way, you can instantiate any instance fields you want inside the default constructor.

Comment: Oh, they constructor is being called, but I don't have control over how it is called (I could be wrong here.)

Like if I want to pass the constructor parameters:
`ResourceClass(new BlueDataSource()) vs ResourceClass(new RedDataSource())`

Answer (score 1):

You might have figured this out; however you can achieve it by using the Jersey filter. I have modified your code to achieve it. This works with Jersey 1.8; for later versions the syntax/names may be different.

```
@Path("somepath")
public class ResourceClass implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    private static DataSource source = new SpecificDataSource();
    @GET
    public String getInfo() {
        return source.queryThatReturnsNumber().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest requestContext) {
        // initialize DataSource source
        return requestContext;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a datasource, I would recommend configuring jndi for your resource. Depending on your server environment there will be different ways to configure your jndi resources. This is a good way to have your Singleton resources configured and or pooled by the application server.

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("jdbc/specificResource");
con = ds.getConnection();
```

If you are using an ejb supported application server (GlassFish, Tomee, Jboss) you can also use the native di support.

```
@Resource(name="specificResource")
DataSource ds;
```

Here is a nice tutorial on the web. 
http://penguindreams.org/blog/running-beans-that-use-application-server-datasources-locally/

As a simple alternative for more complex dependencies. I would recommend jersey-guice dependency injection. I have used many times and it is easy to configure and use.